# SQL Select Boolean Options

Tags: sql, t-sql, formatting, boolean, ssms

Sorry for the vague title, but I'm not exactly sure how I can explain what I want to do in a sentence.

**Preamble:** The SQL syntax for selecting columns that are Boolean is as follows:

```
SELECT MyBooleanColumn FROM MyTableThatHasABooleanColumn
```

This produces the following result:

```
MyBooleanColumn
===============
       1
       1
       1
       0
       1
      ...
```

**Question:** Is there a way to get the following result instead?

```
MyBooleanColumn
===============
     True
     True
     True
     False
     True
      ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT case 
        when MyBooleanColumn = 1 then 'True' 
        else 'False' 
    end as MyBooleanColumn  
FROM MyTableThatHasABooleanColumn
```

Comment: change T for True and F for False.

Comment: Or, when you only want to check the value of a single expression: `case MyBooleanColumn when 1 then 'True' else 'False' end`.

Comment: I didn't know we'd have to do it in the query, but that's quite simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, do it like this:

```
SELECT 
case when MyBooleanColumn = 1 then 'True' else 'False' end as MyBooleanColumn 
FROM MyTableThatHasABooleanColumn
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT case when MyBooleanColumn = 1 then 'True' else 'False' end as MyBooleanColumn  
FROM MyTableThatHasABooleanColumn
```